# how to fix this ACPI BIOS errors and ACPI errors?

Tags: boot, acpi

```
[    1.536862] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.TZ00._TMP.ECPU], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[    1.536928] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
[    1.537009] ACPI: Invalid passive threshold
[    1.537030] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.TZ00._TMP.ECPU], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[    1.537092] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time ago so may no longer be important, but: have you checked that your motherboard or system firmware is on the latest version? Check, and if it isn't, update it.